# Problems installing WPML plugin?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

When I try to install the WPML plugin I get an error screen (like the image below), and the plugin isn't enabled, it's quite frustrating since I can't seem to understand what's wrong. Perhaps the table doesn't exist, but I thought that WPML is supposed to create it?

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Headers and client library minor  version mismatch. Headers:100023 Library:100113 in /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1488
WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
SELECT code FROM es_icl_languages WHERE active = 1

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
SELECT code FROM es_icl_languages WHERE active = 1

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
SELECT code FROM es_icl_languages WHERE active = 1

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
SELECT code FROM es_icl_languages WHERE active = 1

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
SELECT code FROM es_icl_languages WHERE active = 1

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
SELECT code FROM es_icl_languages WHERE active = 1

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
SELECT code FROM es_icl_languages WHERE active = 1

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
SELECT code FROM es_icl_languages WHERE active = 1

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
SELECT code FROM es_icl_languages WHERE active = 1

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_strings' doesn't exist]
ALTER TABLE `es_icl_strings` ADD `gettext_context` TEXT NOT NULL AFTER `status` , ADD `domain_name_context_md5` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER `gettext_context`

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_strings' doesn't exist]
SELECT id, name, value, context as domain, gettext_context FROM es_icl_strings WHERE id > 0

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_strings' doesn't exist]
ALTER TABLE `es_icl_strings` ADD UNIQUE `uc_domain_name_context_md5` (`domain_name_context_md5`) USING BTREE

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_translation_status' doesn't exist]
ALTER TABLE es_icl_translation_status MODIFY COLUMN translation_package longtext NOT NULL

WordPress databasefejl: [Table 'goescoot_booking.es_icl_languages' doesn't exist]
ALTER TABLE es_icl_languages MODIFY default_locale varchar(35), MODIFY tag varchar(35);


Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error upgrading schema for table "icl_languages": ' in /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms2/inc/upgrade-functions/upgrade-3.3.7.php:54 Stack trace: #0 /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms2/inc/upgrade.php(145): include_once() #1 /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms2/inc/upgrade.php(117): icl_upgrade_version('3.3.7') #2 [internal function]: icl_plugin_upgrade('') #3 /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): call_user_func_array('icl_plugin_upgr...', Array) #4 /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-settings.php(276): do_action('plugins_loaded') #5 /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-config.php(83): require_once('/home/goescoot/...') #6 /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/goescoot/...') #7 /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/home/goescoot/... in /home/goescoot/public_html/booking/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms2/inc/upgrade-functions/upgrade-3.3.7.php on line 54
```